# Weird behavior of php datetime object when attempting to retrieve the week number

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following code:

```
$d = new DateTime("2014-12-29");echo $d->format("W");
```

Why does php echoes 01 instead of 52?
   If I write:

```
$d = new DateTime("2014-12-28");echo $d->format("W");
```

then it echoes 52 like I would expect.

Comment: Um, the lines of code you posted are identical

Comment: They are not the same, they have a different day (28 and 29).. His problem is he doesn't know his calender very well..

Comment: @Naruto They *were* the same before OP edited the question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: @TimLewis Well I didn't see an edit.. So I just responded on what I saw.. No hard feelings :)

Comment: @Naruto Yeah, small edits done early in a question's lifespan don't seem to show the "edited" flag.

Comment: Also, your question is backwards, 29th is 01, 28th is 52, your question says that 29th results in 52 "as you expect"... but it clearly doesn't http://3v4l.org/GWRl5

Comment: @Naruto - yeah, I looked stupid yesterday because of a ninja edit, so I made sure and actually pasted both lines into Excel and compared them to make absolutely sure :)

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ That seems to have gotten edited too. OP had them backwards for a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`W` is the ISO-8601 week (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) which will **not** necessarily match with what you'd expect.

> The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the year's first Thursday in it.
>
> ...
>
> If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, it is part of week 53 of the previous year; if on a Saturday, it is part of week 52 (or 53 if the previous year was a leap year); if on a Sunday, it is part of week 52 of the previous year.